# Read Response using RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, postman, restsharp

This question is for testing:-
There is a email website https://www.sharklasers.com where we can create temporary emails. I'm using this site to send email and get some verification code. As of now i'm using selenium which takes some time.

So, I decided to use RestSharp(C#) to read the email.

General Steps:
Step 1: Navigate to https://www.sharklasers.com
Step 2: Edit and set an email id (creates email id with just one click)
Step 3: Sending email to the newly created temp email(from some mail like gmail..)
Step 4: Click on the received email.(Here will get the unique URL for the email)

That's the steps.
This I tried with POSTMAN which is working properly.

POSTMAN Steps: (Captured the traffic using charles proxy)

1.Create Email - POST Request : 
https://www.sharklasers.com/ajax.php?f=set_email_user&email_user=**Emailidhere**&lang=en&site=sharklasers.com&in=+Set+cancel

2.Get list of emails - GET Request : https://www.sharklasers.com/ajax.php?f=get_email_list&offset=0&site=sharklasers.com&in=**Emailidhere**&_=1547991487

I'm having issue with the 2nd step.

Below observations may help you to help me.

Observation in browser:
- Entering the 2nd URL directly to the browser - getting some default information about the sharklasers website.
- First navigate to the sharklasers website , set the email which is created , then in new tab , enter the 2nd URL - getting the expected response.

Observation in POSTMAN:
- Entering the 2nd URL directly to the POSTMAN - getting some default information about the sharklasers website.
- First sending the set the email Request [JSON file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ogWP0LhU-QBvNEGjnsDUarQmE1DvOIcm), then sending Request to the 2nd URL [JSON file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AXitmbfbmX2KUEU16843-ikjOA7m0ZK2), getting the expected response.

Observation in Visual Studio (RestSharp C#)
- Entering the 2nd URL directly to the POSTMAN - getting some default information about the sharklasers website.
- First sending the set the email Request , then sending Request to the 2nd URL - **getting the same default information about the sharklasers website. NOT Getting the expected response**

**Set Email RestSharp code taken from POSTMAN:**

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.sharklasers.com/ajax.php?f=set_email_user&email_user=testemailstackoverflow&lang=en&site=sharklasers.com&in=+Set+cancel");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "ddae1b83-b974-4e9b-a013-940c2e91d50a");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

**Get Email RestSharp taken from POSTMAN:**

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.sharklasers.com/ajax.php?f=get_email_list&offset=0&site=sharklasers.com&in=testemailstackoverflow&_=1547991487");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "7625df90-9ee9-46e6-b9ca-568dde93618e");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Now i want to get the same response in Visual studio(Restsharp C#) which is observed in POSTMAN and browser.

This question may be little confusing. If any questions regarding the question , please ask me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have the basic code provided by POSTMAN, why not give it a shot yourself? Once you have run into a specific problem we can assist, but we don't do general code writing, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply gilliduck.. But you didn't read the question fully i think. I already tried with code and i mentioned the observation above in the section.. Observation in Visual Studio (RestSharp C#) :     using the 2nd URL in the Visual studio code - getting some default information about the sharklasers website. - First sending the set the email Request , then sending Request to the 2nd URL - getting the same default information about the sharklasers website. NOT Getting the expected response

Comment: found myself missing cookies from the first request's response was the issue. Now it works by using the previous request's cookies for the next request.